# Sunshine app not displaying live data

Tags: java, android, json

I'm following Udacity's Android development tutorial at the moment, and I've just finished lesson 2, where my app is supposed to be able to download information from the Internet.

Here's my code in the MainActivity Java class:

```
//package name
//list of imported libraries

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add
            (R.id.container, new ForecastFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here's my code in the ForecastFragment Java class:

```
//package name
//list of imported libraries
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

public ForecastFragment() {
    //nada, zilch, nichts, sweet Fanny Adams
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute("Dublin");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] data = {
            "2/3 Clear - Low: 2°C - High: 6°C",
            "3/3 Snow - Low: 0°C - High: 4°C",
            "4/3 Clear - Low: 3°C - High: 7°C",
            "5/3 Rain - Low: 5°C - High: 9°C",
            "6/3 Rain - Low: 7°C - High: 10°C",
            "7/3 Cloudy - Low: 8°C - High: 10°C",
            "8/3 Cloudy - Low: 7°C - High: 11°C"};
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

    // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    weekForecast);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listView = (ListView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
     * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
     */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }

        for (String s : resultStrs) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
        }
        return resultStrs;

    }
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 7;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast string: " + forecastJsonStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
            // Data has been returned from the server
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem is, even if I press "Refresh", the screen won't display the live data, and instead displays the "dummy data" from the 7 strings in the array. I've even tried to copy and paste the code from the github repository for this app, but that doesn't work: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIZwC.png

On top of that, the drop-down menu from the action bar has duplicated itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEe0z.png

Have I made a mistake somewhere, like placing a method out of order? I'm totally new to Android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing one call to `notifyDataSetChanged` to inform the adapter the underlying data has been updated. Try this :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    if (result != null) {
        mForecastAdapter.clear();
        for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
            mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
        }
        // Update adapter
        mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And you need to launch the task somewhere, `onActivityCreated` inside the `ForecastFragment` seems a good choice :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new FetchWeatherTask().execute("London");
}
```

Comment: It's still not refreshing, should I have added .notifyDataSetChanged() to other places?

Comment: Can you check if there is an error logged in Logcat ? The parsing of the json may have failed. You could also log the content of result in onPostExecute to check if some data is returned

Comment: Yeah, there's plenty of errors in Logcat. :/ I'm getting a warning telling me that requestLayout() was improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon

Comment: As I said, I think you should log operations in your AsyncTask (is the url you're creating correct if you use it a browser ? Do you get data in onPostExecute ? ...), just to make sure where the problem comes from.

Comment: I've just checked Logcat, and searched through it using "app: [Sunshine's package filename]" and even though I put in a few verbose logs, those verbose logs aren't showing up in Logcat. I've tried the URL that I've created, and the only thing wrong with it was that it was referring to the weather in a town called Dublin in the USA rather than the Irish city. I'm starting to think that I'm not even reaching the AsyncTask in my app.

Comment: Indeed, I couldn't find where you lanched the task. I added a suggestion about that in my answer, hopefully that will help a bit.

Comment: It still won't refresh, and nothing's showing up in Logcat.

Comment: *facepalm* I made a typo when putting in onActivityCreated(), but now my app's crashing. On the bright side, the JSON string is finally appearing in Logcat.

Comment: I just got it to work now, I forgot to add super.onActivityCreated() into onActivityCreated().